# How to align my equation to left?

Tags: math-mode, align

I want to display four equations which have different length. I want they align left like this.[image]

But my code give this[image]

The following are my code:

```
$$\begin{aligned} p(a) &=p(a) p(a \rightarrow a)+p(b) p(b \rightarrow a)+p(c) p(c \rightarrow a)+p(d) p(d \rightarrow a) \\  
&={\scriptstyle \frac{1}{2} \frac{2}{3}+\frac{1}{4} \frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}=\frac{1}{2}}
\end{aligned}$$
$$\begin{aligned} p(b) &=p(a) p(a \rightarrow b)+p(b) p(b \rightarrow b)+p(c) p(c \rightarrow b) \\ 
&={\scriptstyle\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{4} \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3} \frac{1}{3}=\frac{1}{4}} \end{aligned}$$
$$\begin{aligned} p(c) &=p(a) p(a \rightarrow c)+p(b) p(b \rightarrow c)+p(c) p(c \rightarrow c)+p(d) p(d \rightarrow c) \\ 
&={\scriptstyle\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{12}+\frac{1}{4} \frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{8} 0+\frac{1}{8}=\frac{1}{8}} \end{aligned}$$
$$\begin{aligned} p(d) &=p(a) p(a \rightarrow d)+p(c) p(c \rightarrow d)+p(d) p(d \rightarrow d) \\ 
&={\scriptstyle\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{12}+\frac{1}{8} \frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{8} \frac{1}{3}=\frac{1}{3}} \end{aligned}$$
```

Can anyone tell me what I can do?

Comment: never use `$$` in latex, use `\[`  and then the `fleqn` option will left align equations.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a proposal

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
p(a)&=p(a) p(a \rightarrow a)+p(b) p(b \rightarrow a)+p(c) p(c \rightarrow a)+p(d) p(d \rightarrow a)\\
&\;={\scriptstyle \frac{1}{2} \frac{2}{3}+\frac{1}{4} \frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}=\frac{1}{2}}\\
p(b)&=p(a) p(a \rightarrow b)+p(b) p(b \rightarrow b)+p(c) p(c \rightarrow b)\\
&\;={\scriptstyle\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{4} \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3} \frac{1}{3}=\frac{1}{4}}\\
p(c)&=p(a) p(a \rightarrow c)+p(b) p(b \rightarrow c)+p(c) p(c \rightarrow c)+p(d) p(d \rightarrow c)\\
&\;={\scriptstyle\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{12}+\frac{1}{4} \frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{8} 0+\frac{1}{8}=\frac{1}{8}}\\
p(d)&=p(a) p(a \rightarrow d)+p(c) p(c \rightarrow d)+p(d) p(d \rightarrow d)\\
&\;={\scriptstyle\frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{12}+\frac{1}{8} \frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{8} \frac{1}{3}=\frac{1}{3}}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Why do you use `\scriptstyle`? It is very hard to read the fractions! Use `\tfrac` instead!

You should remove `\;` in the `&\;={\scriptstyle...` lines to align the `=`s. I prefer that way.

---

I strongly recommend this one

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
p(a)&=p(a) p(a \rightarrow a)+p(b) p(b \rightarrow a)+p(c) p(c \rightarrow a)+p(d) p(d \rightarrow a)\\
&=\tfrac{1}{2} \tfrac{2}{3}+\tfrac{1}{4} \tfrac{1}{3}+\tfrac{1}{3}+\tfrac{1}{3}=\tfrac{1}{2}\\
p(b)&=p(a) p(a \rightarrow b)+p(b) p(b \rightarrow b)+p(c) p(c \rightarrow b)\\
&=\tfrac{1}{2} \tfrac{1}{6}+\tfrac{1}{4} \tfrac{1}{2}+\tfrac{1}{3} \tfrac{1}{3}=\tfrac{1}{4}\\
p(c)&=p(a) p(a \rightarrow c)+p(b) p(b \rightarrow c)+p(c) p(c \rightarrow c)+p(d) p(d \rightarrow c)\\
&=\tfrac{1}{2} \tfrac{1}{12}+\tfrac{1}{4} \tfrac{1}{6}+\tfrac{1}{8} 0+\tfrac{1}{8}=\tfrac{1}{8}\\
p(d)&=p(a) p(a \rightarrow d)+p(c) p(c \rightarrow d)+p(d) p(d \rightarrow d)\\
&=\tfrac{1}{2} \tfrac{1}{12}+\tfrac{1}{8} \tfrac{1}{3}+\tfrac{1}{8} \tfrac{1}{3}=\tfrac{1}{3}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I use '\scriptstyle' because I want the second line of the equation to be small.

Comment: @chole Then you should use `\tfrac` instead of `\scriptstyle\frac`.

Comment: +1 for recommending `\tfrac` in place of `\scriptstyle\frac`.

Comment: @chole If my answer helps you, please mark your question as resolved by clicking the checkmark on the left of my answer.

Comment: +1 yes as I commented under the question the direct answer why there was no left alignment was due to using `$$` but If I had answered I would also have suggested `align*` rather than `\[\begin{aligned}` :-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Of course the issue can be solved quite easily with `fleqn`, but we all know `align*` is far better than `aligned` in this job :)

Answer (score 5):

I propose this layout, using the `fleqn` environment and, as in my opinion, medium sized fractions will look best, I also use  the `\medmath` and `\mfrac` commands, each from `nccmath`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, nccmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{fleqn}
\begin{align*}
p(a)&=p(a) p(a \rightarrow a)+p(b) p(b \rightarrow a)+p(c) p(c \rightarrow a)+p(d) p(d \rightarrow a)\\
&\quad= \medmath{\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{2}{3}+\frac{1}{4}\cdot \frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}}=\mfrac{1}{2} \\[1ex]
p(b)&=p(a) p(a \rightarrow b)+p(b) p(b \rightarrow b)+p(c) p(c \rightarrow b)\\
&\quad= \medmath{\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{4}\cdot \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}\cdot \frac{1}{3}}=\mfrac{1}{4} \\[1ex]
p(c)&=p(a) p(a \rightarrow c)+p(b) p(b \rightarrow c)+p(c) p(c \rightarrow c)+p(d) p(d \rightarrow c)\\
&\quad= \medmath{\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{12}+\frac{1}{4}\cdot \frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{8}\,0 + \frac{1}{8}}=\mfrac{1}{8} \\[1ex]
p(d)&=p(a) p(a \rightarrow d)+p(c) p(c \rightarrow d)+p(d) p(d \rightarrow d)\\
&\quad= \medmath{\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{12}+\frac{1}{8}\cdot \frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{8\cdot } \frac{1}{3}}=\mfrac{1}{3}
\end{align*}
\end{fleqn}

\end{document}
```

[image]